# A Triangle and Intersecting Segments

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $D, E, F$ be the centres of the sides $BC, AC, AB$ of a triangle $ABC$. How do I show that the segments $AD, BE, CF$ intersect at a common point that divides each of them in the ratio $2 : 1$.

Any hints,

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

> $1>$ Check the definition of the **centroid** of a Triangle
>
> $2>$ Check in what ratio the cetroid divies the lines (in question) .